# Why can't I load ANY of the UK Lung Deaths datasets in R?

Tags: r, dataset

Was just trying to work my way through the new fable package, and wanted to reproduce the example [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/fable/versions/0.0.0.9000), that uses monthly UK lung deaths. The "tsibbledata" package shown in the linked page doesn't seem to exist, but the "datasets" package has datasets called "fdeaths" and "mdeaths" that I thought I could use instead. What could be simpler?

I have loaded the datasets package, and when I run data(), both show up in the list. Yet, if I try to load them, e.g., "data(fdeaths)" plus literally every possible variation on that I can think of, I get an error:

```
data(fdeaths) 
Warning message:
In data(fdeaths) : data set ‘fdeaths’ not found
```

Whyeeeeee?

And sorry in advance for whatever question-asking infractions I've committed. I'm sure someone will tell me.

Comment: You can access/install `tsibbledata` package from here: https://github.com/tidyverts/tsibbledata

Comment: Thanks @PoGibas!

Answer (score 2):

The data set is called `UKLungDeaths` and those data are found as objects within that data set. For example, try,

```
data(UKLungDeaths)
```

then,

```
fdeaths
```

giving,

```
#       Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov  Dec
# 1974  901  689  827  677  522  406  441  393  387  582  578  666
# 1975  830  752  785  664  467  438  421  412  343  440  531  771
# 1976  767 1141  896  532  447  420  376  330  357  445  546  764
# 1977  862  660  663  643  502  392  411  348  387  385  411  638
# 1978  796  853  737  546  530  446  431  362  387  430  425  679
# 1979  821  785  727  612  478  429  405  379  393  411  487  574
```

Comment: Also, after loading the data, the OP could try `ls(pattern = "deaths$")` to see the names of the other datasets.

Comment: Okay; yep. For some reason, UKLungDeaths doesn't show up in the autocomplete, but if I type it all the way in, it loads the three datasets (ldeaths, fdeaths, and mdeaths). Good grief. THANKS. It's Friday; I can't brain good any more.

Comment: Just out of even more curiosity, why doesn't it show up in the autocomplete like all of the other datasets?

Comment: @Steph That's a good question. I have no idea. One thing worth mentioning about viewing all available datasets using `data()`: if there's a name in parentheses, then that's the name of the dataset and the other name given is the name of the object within that dataset. If there's just one name given, then that's the name of the dataset.

Comment: Ahh. Thanks for that. I think I tried *including* the parenthetical "parent" with, e.g., "mdeaths", but hadn't actually tried it alone, or if I did, when it didn't autocomplete, I figured it was a no-go. Once I went ahead and typed it all in, of course it loaded no problem.